# Terraform .11 to .12 conversion of deeply nested data

Tags: terraform

So, in my old .11 code, I have a file where i my output modules locals section, I'm building:

```
this_assigned_nat_ip = google_compute_instance.this_public.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip--
```

Which later gets fed to the output statement.  This module could create N instances. So what it used to do was give me the first nat ip on the first access_config block on the first network interface of all the instances we created.  (Someone locally wrote the code so we know that there's only going to be one network interface with one access config block).
How do I translate that to t12?  I'm unsure of the syntax to keep the nesting.

Update:
Here's a chunk of the raw data out of a terraform show from tf11 (slightly sanitized)

```
module.gcp_bob_servers_ams.google_compute_instance.this_public.0:
  machine_type = n1-standard-2
  min_cpu_platform =
  network_interface.# = 1
  network_interface.0.access_config.# = 1
  network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip =
  network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip = 1.2.3.4
  network_interface.0.access_config.0.network_tier = PREMIUM
```

Terraform show of equivalent host in tf12:

```
# module.bob.module.bob_gcp_ams.module.atom_d.google_compute_instance.this[1]:
resource "google_compute_instance" "this" {
    allow_stopping_for_update = true

    network_interface {
        name               = "nic0"
        network            = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/stuff-scratch/global/networks/scratch-public"
        network_ip         = "10.112.112.6"
        subnetwork         = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/stuff-scratch/regions/europe-west4/subnetworks/scratch-europe-west4-x-public-subnet"
        subnetwork_project = "stuff-scratch"

        access_config {
            nat_ip       = "35.204.132.177"
            network_tier = "PREMIUM"
        }
    }

    scheduling {
        automatic_restart   = true
        on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE"
        preemptible         = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include in your question the result of the `terraform 0.12upgrade` command when applied to that particular expression, and the full error message you saw when Terraform failed to evaluate it? That will hopefully help to understand what part of the expression isn't working as expected, and thus to see how we might adjust it.

Comment: That is the output!  The "before" query was exactly the same except it was wrapped in "${}".

Comment: What happened when you ran `terraform plan` on the configuration containing this expression, and how did that differ from what you _expected_ to happen based on the 0.11 behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `this[*].network_interface[*].access_config[*].nat_ip[*]` gave me what I needed.  Given there's only every going to be one address on the interface, it comes out fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly `this_assigned_nat_ip` is a list of IPs. You should be able to get the same thing in Terraform 0.12 by doing:

```
this_assigned_nat_ip = [for i in google_compute_instance.this_public : i.network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip]
```

I did not test is, so I might have some small syntax error, but the `for` is the key to get that done.